# emacs on mac os x, how to get spell check to work

Tags: macos, emacs, spell-checking, aspell, flyspell

I'm moving from Windows to Mac, and I've spent the whole night trying to get emacs to work.

I've installed [GNU emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and simply copied over my Windows `.emacs` file, which seems to work ok, except for spell check. I installed [cocoAspell](http://cocoaspell.leuski.net/) and followed this [setup instruction](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CocoAspell) to add the path and change ispell to aspell, but when I run spell check, I got

```
Error: The file "/use/local/lib/aspell-0.60/english" can not be opened for reading.
```

and FlySpell does not work either.

It seems like it's looking at the wrong directory, but I already have

```
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell"
      ispell-dictionary "english"
      ispell-dictionary-alist
      (let ((default '("[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "[']" nil
                       ("-B" "-d" "english" "--dict-dir"
                        "/Library/Application Support/cocoAspell/aspell6-en-6.0-0")
                       nil iso-8859-1)))
        `((nil ,@default)
          ("english" ,@default))))
```

which points to the right dictionary directory "/Library/Application Support/cocoAspell/aspell6-en-6.0-0". I can't figure out why I got the error and how to fix it.

---

**Update:**

Now I have removed my GNU emacs and cocoAspell, and re-installed (and linked) emacs/aspell using homebrew as @katspaugh suggested. I removed the code shown above, leave only

```
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
```

Now when I run spell check, I got

```
Searching for program: No such file or directory, aspell
```

I have already linked aspell with `brew link aspell`, why it still cannot find it?

Comment: Did the error message really say `use/local`? In that case you have a typo somewhere -- it should be `usr/local`.

Comment: If you're using CUA-mode and other Mac-ish/Windows-y features, you may want to consider [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) instead of GNU Emacs. Among many other useful features, it also comes with aspell properly configured, and lets you use the OS X system spellchecker instead if you prefer.

Comment: See also: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33865/spelling-check-in-emacs-25-2-on-mac-os-sierra

Answer (score 29):

Here's a working solution:

- Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)
- `brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-gnutls`
- `brew install aspell`
- `open -a Emacs`
- <kbd>M-x ispell</kbd>

Enjoy!

Comment: Use aspell rather then ispell.

Comment: I see that aspell has better Unicode support. Need to check if the recipe above works the same way with aspell.

Comment: It should.  Aspell provides the same interface as ispell, and both, ispell and flyspell, should pick it up automatically.

Comment: Yep, it appears `ispell` and `aspell` can be used interchangeably. By the way, Homebrew, unfortunately, doesn't have any additional dictionary packages for neither of the two.

Comment: Thanks! Is this a separate emacs installation or does it just adds aspell to the GNU emacs I've already have?

Comment: @LWZ, it's separate, so you'll have to delete the other Emacs and aspell.

Comment: @katspaugh The dictionaries are included in the formulae themselves.  Just take a look at their arguments, and select the ones you need, e.g. `brew install aspell --with-lang-de`.

Comment: @katspaugh By the way, install Emacs with `brew install emacs --cocoa --srgb --with-gnu-tls`.  This improves color appearance, and enables encrypted network traffic for Emacs.

Comment: @katspaugh Now I've removed the other emacs and installed this one using your method, but when I run spell check I still got the exact same error as shown in OP.

Comment: @katspaugh I tried removing the code but emacs couldn't find aspell. I think it's because aspell didn't "link" properly (I don't know what it means). I got a warning when I reinstall aspell. Would you mind open a chat and help me with this?

Comment: FYI, I ran this code and got a warning that `emacs: --cocoa was deprecated; using --with-cocoa instead!`

Comment: Adding languages now fails with `invalid option: --with-lang-en`. Install with `brew install aspell`.

Answer (score 12):

I use aspell from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Simply:

```
brew install aspell --with-lang-en
```

Then, make sure your brew bin directory is in your Emacs `exec-path` variable. If you use `/usr/local` as your brew prefix then it will just work since that path is included in `exec-path` by default. Otherwise you'll need this somewhere in your .emacs:

```
  (setq exec-path (append "/path/to/brew/bin" exec-path)))
```

You can also accomplish the same thing using the `customize` interface with "`M-x customize-variable RET exec-path RET`" and then using the gui to add a path.

This will work on any Emacs, including the one from [Emacs for Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com), the one from brew, or the system Emacs.

Comment: Adding languages now fails with `invalid option: --with-lang-en`. Install with `brew install aspell`.

Answer (score 4):

I build on the answers by katspaugh, David Caldwell, and Ébe Isaac, and made it work with the latest versions.

Install aspell, for example with `brew`:

```
brew install aspell
```

`brew` symlinks to `/usr/local/bin` and you can verify the installation:

```
$ which aspell
/usr/local/bin/aspell
```

Now tell Emacs about this location, e.g. adding this line in `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "/opt/local/bin/aspell")
```

Launch `M-x ispell` in a buffer and it works.

To install with `ports`, see other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a MacPorts solution to the problem.
(Credits to this [link](https://truongtx.me/2013/09/13/emacs-spell-checking-macos/))

`$ sudo port install aspell`

Then install one of aspell's dictionaries for the respective language support

`$ sudo port install aspell-dict-en`

Then add the following line to your init.el or .emacs file.

```lisp
(setq ispell-program-name "/opt/local/bin/aspell")
```

It worked for me.

Note: "sudo ports install ispell" works as well, but it is not as efficient and flexible as aspell.

Answer (score 1):

Making a symbolic link in /usr/bin on OS X 10.12 (Sierra) is not permitted or necessary (or a good idea).

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ispell /usr/bin/ispell
ln: /usr/bin/ispell: Operation not permitted
```

I used that hack for years, but was finally forced to figure out the right solution when the last upgrade deleted it. I used [homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install ispell and apsell and would get which ever one I set in `~/.emacs` with

```
$ cat ~/.emacs
(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")
```

There is a similar discussion of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126951/emacs-cannot-find-flyspell-ispell).

Answer (score 0):

It also works if you use fink instead than home-brew. ispell will be in /sw/bin
and the string to add to .emacs file will be:

(setq ispell-program-name "/sw/bin/ispell")

Answer (score 0):

Installing aspell, and adding `(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")` in the `init.el` does not work for me. I had to make a symbolic link `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/aspell /usr/bin/ispell`, then emacs flyspell-mode works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs installed with `brew cask install emacs` will come with a built in spell checker called `m-x ispell`.

You have to do two things to get this to work.

1. `brew install aspell` or maybe `brew install aspell --with-lang-en`
2. go to emacs and evaluate this function or better yet put it in your init file `(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")`

Note: the location of aspell can be found using `which aspell` in macOS terminal which should be equal tot step 2. above.