# Terraform - version differences

Tags: terraform

Why, when I run `terraform -v` do I get:

```
Terraform v0.9.6

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.9.7. You can update by downloading from www.terraform.io
```

i.e. implying the latest version is `0.9.7` BUT, at the time of this post (and when I ran the `terraform -v` command) https://www.terraform.io/ says `0.9.8` as does `brew` via http://brewformulas.org/Terraform

Comment: 0.9.8 was a last-second hotfix for a bug introduced in 0.9.7 though, so that may be a reason. Hashicorp also doesn't have a good qa/build/release process for their software and does not follow semantic versioning rules, so, you know.

Comment: Which -a terraform , brew will install multiple versions but not update the symlink.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371626/1794802

Answer (score -1):

Install the required binary package (depending upon your OS) from Download page. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases

Unzip the .zip file to the bin directory as per your OS

For mac

unzip terraform_0.9.11_darwin_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin

Now check the terraform version:

terraform version

Terraform v0.9.1

Comment: This answer is not at all related to the asked question of why the version discrepancy happened.